# TeamCity - Unmet requirements: DotNetFramework4.5_x86 exists

Tags: teamcity, agent

I am very new to TeamCity and currently have a problem with an incompatible agent:

```
Unmet requirements: 
DotNetFramework4.5_x86 exists
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Do I have to add a reference to .NET 4.5 somewhere?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an agent requirement that DotNetFramework4.5_x86 exists, but on this agent it doesn't. If the requirement is required, you need to install .NET on that agent machine. TeamCity has detected that .NET is not installed on this machine so your build cannot run.

If the requirement is incorrect and not needed by your build, it can be removed by going under:

```
Edit build Configuration > Agent Requirements
```

Then in the table of agent requirements you will see:

```
DotNetFramework4.5_x86 exists
```

And there is a button to delete this requirement. Once you delete the requirement, the agent will appear under 'Compatible Agents'.

Comment: Just a note that if you know the framework is installed, but the agent isn't showing the parameter, try restarting the build agent service to force a rescan.

Answer (score 3):

We had an agent that was working fine, but suddenly stopped with the same unmet requirement from the original question.

I tried restarting the agent service as @arcain suggested, but that did not work. So I went to the TeamCity "Agent Summary" page and disabled and then reenabled the agent and it started working again.

Comment: Found the same using TeamCity Professional 2017.1.4 (build 47070)

Comment: Ran into the same issue after upgrading to 2017.2.1, but here neither restarting nor disabling/enabling works.

Comment: In my case, it turned out that the xunit-teamcity plugin was to blame: Updating that resolved the issue.