# How to resolve this unmet agent requirement: "DotNetFramework4.0_x86 exists"?

Tags: teamcity

We have tried all options below, but it's not working.

We are using Visual Studio 2012 and Jetbrains Teamcity version 7.1

While configuring the agent I selected the runnert type as VisualStudio(sln) and when I configure and run the agent it says

`Unmet requirements:DotNetFramework4.5_x86 exists`

I went through all the steps explained in the below mentioned blogs and this didn't help. Please suggest me if any new solution is in place.

http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5316474

[TeamCity - Unmet requirements: DotNetFramework4.5_x86 exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13312796/teamcity-unmet-requirements-dotnetframework4-5-x86-exists)

Answer (score 1):

Then link you posted is about Visual studio 2010(.net 4.0), Your using Visual studio 2012 which contains support for applications built in .net 4.5. Do you have .net 4.5 installed on the agent machine?  Install .net 4.5 as unless yor trying to target builds not targeted at 4.5 and not building using 4.5 you need it (and if you were just set it to target vs2010 instead?).

Comment: which is the latest version of msbuild to install?